# SoundCloud API: documentation for attachments_uri?

Tags: soundcloud

The example track in the SoundCloud API /tracks documentation (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) has a field "attachments_uri", but I don't see anything in the docs about it.  Anybody know anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attachments_uri` field is used by some undocumented functionality that we have actually deprecated. It's there for backward compatibility with some older apps.

Short answer: you can safely ignore it :-)

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that it was possible to attach a binary file to a soundcloud track. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible but deprecated. We can't guarantee that functionality will be around for long, so I wouldn't suggest building on it.